# R Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip, br content encodings

Tags: r, curl, libcurl, httr

I have had a working R Script for the past year that pulls in data from a website. Suddenly, the script stopped working. I have not made any changes to the script nor had I made any changes to the linux server running rstudio server prior to receiving this error (I have since made changes in trying to fix the error). Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post the URL (I know, this makes it extremely unhelpful in troubleshooting).

The part of the script that stopped working looks like this:

```
         response <- GET(
                url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                add_headers(
                        'Accept' = "application/json",
                        'accept-encoding' = 'gzip, deflate, br',
                        'authorization' = xxxxxxxx,
                        'user-agent' = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
                        'sec-fetch-dest' = 'empty',
                        'sec-fetch-mode' = 'cors',
                        'sec-fetch-site' = 'same-site'
                )
        )
```

In the past, I would receive the appropriate data from the website with the following:

```
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
```

However, starting yesterday, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip, br content encodings.
```

If I run my script from my Windows Desktop RStudio version, I'm getting the correct results so it seems something has changed on the linux server; however, I have reinstalled R, RStudio, along with the curl and httr packages as well as libcurl4 on the linux server to no avail.

Comment: My first thought would be something changed on the website server, not your RStudio Linux server. Are you able to retrieve the data through another means such as making the GET request via Postman or command line curl? You may want to try adding `verbose()` to your `GET` call to possibly get more information

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. I get the results required when running the script from my Windows desktop version of RStudio. But I'll definitely add verbose() to my GET and see what results I get.

Answer (score 0):

Magically started working again. Must have been the site, but I was told there were no changes made to the site. It works now and that's all that matters.