# "Unrecognized content encoding type" error when uploading an image

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, woocommerce

I am trying to fetch images that I have uploaded to my CDN. I used `canvas.toDataURL` to convert my images to PNGs before upload.

I get the following error when I try to fetch the images: `Error: cURL error 61: Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip, br content encodings`

So first I created this image using FabricJS:
Then I am exporting it as a PNG using:

```
const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    format: 'png'
})
```

Then I am uploading it to my S3 CDN using:

```
async function uploadPNG(dataURL, filePath) {
  const buf = Buffer.from(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    ContentType: 'image/png',
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    Body: buf,
    Key: filePath
  }

  return await s3.upload(uploadParams).promise()
}
```

Then I am trying to upload that image (which is now in the S3 CDN) to a WooCommerce site using their API.
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.blankt.com/product/s/AY6AJSHMXnf2ReCZOu.png

Here is part of that API request:

```
{
  "name": "AY6AJSHMXnf2ReCZOu",
  "type": "variable",
  "regular_price": "9.90",
  "sku": "AY6AJSHMXnf2ReCZOu",

  ...

  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "src": "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.blankt.com/product/s/AY6AJSHMXnf2ReCZOu.png"
    }
  ],
  "attributes" : [
    {
      "name"      : "Size",
      "variation" : true,
      "visible"   : true,
      "options"   : [ "A3", "A4", "A5" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the response that I get:
[image]

This problem seem to only appear when I try to upload the image using the API, if I download and upload the image manually to WooCommerce, there are no problems.

Comment: ... yes they do compress the image data, the PNG format is basically the pixel data deflated, The file however is not re-compressed over. **Your error has nothing to do with these methods.** The problem lies in the request you made to the server. Show how this request has been made please.

Comment: Thanks for you comment Kaiido, I will add some additional information in the question

Comment: I edited your question so that the correct audience can find it correctly (unfortunately I am not myself part of this "correct audience", since I know nothing of WooCommerce and their APIs.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, I didn't think that WooCommerce was the issue since I didn't find a lot of questions / cases of this particular error.

Comment: 1. Did you copy the image url and paste in a new tab to see if the image is visible ? 2. is it working now ? The error doesn't seem to be saying the problem is at your end, it's a response from `curl` (wc backend) that is trying to fetch the image in the woocommerce system. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66921693/r-unrecognized-content-encoding-type-libcurl-understands-deflate-gzip-br-cont) [this](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2146) and [this](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/179)

Comment: Is the buf constant still encoded with base64 after the `Buffer.from`? Doesn’t it decode it?

Comment: @Towkir 1. Yes the image is fully visible when opened in a separate tab. 2. It is currently not working.

Comment: @RatajS I currently don't know the answer to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that you're providing the invalid content encoding in your s3 upload, where you provide the parameter `ContentEncoding: 'base64'`.

The [s3 SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) for the `upload` method is somewhat unclear in the specifics of handling the `ContentEncoding` parameter:

> ContentEncoding — (String)
> Specifies what content encodings have been applied to the object and thus what decoding mechanisms must be applied to obtain the media-type referenced by the Content-Type header field.

But my suspicion is that it is simply passed along as the `Content-Encoding` HTTP header ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding)) when the object is accessed. In which case the image loads fine in your browser because it's smart (or perhaps dumb) enough to discard the encoding that it doesn't recognize, however WooCommerce's backend does not do that, and instead produces an error.

**Solution**: remove the `ContentEncoding` from your s3 upload params -- you're not uploading encoded content in the first place, since you decode the base64 data to raw bytes when you pass it to `Buffer.from` with the `'base64'` encoding parameter (See [Buffer.from(string[, encoding])](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) and [character encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) in Node.JS docs)